# Why people name a directory "vendor" which contains all programs that are made by others?

Tags: svn, git, version-control, cvs, history

I assume it is because of a historical reason and want to know how/why it's decided.

Comment: have never seen such a directory in projects. Are you sure it is not some local policy or smth similar? Though maybe I'm just too young.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's an old tradition in cvs of 'vendor branches'. Imagine yourself working at a company. Most of the code you're putting in CVS is yours. But you also incorporate something from someone else. (Think, 'headers from some third-party library in c.') Someone you buy it from. a 'vendor'. The concept of the vendor branch was supposed to help with the problem of 'ok, here's a new release from the vendor, some files are new, some deleted, some changed. Now what?'

Answer (score 0):

That is not usual. But some people need to control what programs they use, and as you said, because of historical reasons they named it vendor or third party. I have seen some projects using this, but they are just a few.

Answer (score 0):

vendor is usually used for vendor branches, i.e. branches used to apply small changes needed by your software inside externally developed software. Read more about them [in the SVN book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.vendorbr.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think it comes from Ruby on Rails. At lest that's where I have first seen it.